# importing a CSV and assign to current user ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I am trying to import a CSV file and assign the import to the current user.  So, it will add the user_id to the each row of the csv import.

I am missing something because it still doesn't find the user and add it to the row...

**Controller :**

```
 def import
    Inventory.import(params[:file], current_user.id)
    redirect_to root_url, notice: "Inventory imported."
  end
```

**Method:**

```
class Inventory < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user

def self.import(file, user_id)
  allowed_attributes = [ "user_id", "id","description","part_number","price","created_at","updated_at", "alternate_part_number", "condition_code", "qty", "mfg_code", "serial_number", "part_comments"]
  spreadsheet = open_spreadsheet(file)
  header = spreadsheet.row(1)
  (2..spreadsheet.last_row).each do |i|
    row = Hash[[header, spreadsheet.row(i)].transpose]
    inventory = find_by_id(row["id"]) || new
    inventory.attributes = row.to_hash.select { |k,v| allowed_attributes.include? k }
    inventory.save!
  end
end
```

I end up with this error:
[import error ruby](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5CaZL.png)

**Thank you for any help!!**

Comment: Does your CSV include valid user_ids in the user_id column? Or do you want to use the user_id you provided in the method call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(...)
inventory = (...)
inventory.user_id = user_id
inventory.save!`

however it's better you send along the user rather than it's id:

controller:
`Inventory.import(params[:file], current_user)`

model:

```
 def import(file, user)
  inventory = Inventory.new
  inventory.attributes = {}
  inventory.user = user
  inventory.save!
end
```

Comment: thanks!  I am still getting:      NameError in InventoriesController#import
undefined local variable or method `user' for #<Class:0x007fe9a2a9e320>

Extracted source (around line #12):
10
11
12
13
14
15
              
    inventory = find_by_id(row["id"]) || new
    inventory.attributes = row.to_hash.select { |k,v| allowed_attributes.include? k }
    inventory.user = user
    inventory.save!
  end
end